# タグのマージ: [テスト]&[testing]

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案

現在 [テスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%86%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88)と[testing](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing)が存在しますが、同じものだと思うので、マージしたほうが良いのではないかと考えます。

マージする場合、何をメインにするかですが、タグwikiは[testing](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing)の方のみ存在しますが、ja.stackoverflowである事を考慮すると、メインは[テスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%83%86%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88)のほうがいいような気もします。
ちなみに[testing](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing)のwikiには

> testing（ソフトウェアテスト）は、コンピュータのプログラムを実行し、正しく動作するか...

とあり、[ソフトウェアテスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%bd%e3%83%95%e3%83%88%e3%82%a6%e3%82%a7%e3%82%a2%e3%83%86%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88)も選択肢に入るのかもしれません。

Comment: タグシノニムにするということでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

testing → テスト　を実行しました：

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest